# Is the first row of an HTML table with <th> tags row 0?

Tags: html

Is the first row of an HTML table with **th tags** meant to be row 0? Because if I style the table rows with

```
.t01 tr:nth-child(even) {
    color: red;
}

.t01 tr:nth-child(odd) {
    color: white;
}
```

both the first row and the second row have the text color white. But the second row should be red, because 2 is even.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Comment: `th` tags would not effect those CSS statements as you are looking for even and odd numbered `tr` children. What you have should work - can you please provide a fiddle or code snippet illustrating the issue?

Comment: From the link @SLaks mentioned above look specifically for the `Functional notation` section. That will clear it up for you (`<An+B>`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without your Code it's hard to help, it shoud work as it is.

My guess is, you are using `<thead>` and `<tbody>` which results in 2 containers holding `<tr>` tags. So the nth-child of `<thead>` is odd and the nth-child of `<tbody>` is odd too

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.container div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container p {
  font-size: 8pt;
}

.t01 {
  background-color: #3d3d3d;
}

.t01 tr:nth-child(even) {
  color: red;
}

.t01 tr:nth-child(odd) {
  color: white;
}

.t02 {
  background-color: #3d3d3d;
}

.t02 tr:nth-child(even) {
  color: red;
}

.t02 tr:nth-child(odd) {
  color: white;
}

.t03 {
  background-color: #3d3d3d;
}

.t03 thead tr:first-child {
  color: red;
}

.t03 tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  color: red;
}

.t03 tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <table class="t01">
      <tr>
        <th>A</th>
        <th>B</th>
        <th>C</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <p>No &lt;thead&gt; &amp; &lt;tbody&gt;</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <table class="t02">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>A</th>
          <th>B</th>
          <th>C</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <p>With &lt;thead&gt; &amp; &lt;tbody&gt;</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <table class="t03">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>A</th>
          <th>B</th>
          <th>C</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <p>Fix for &lt;thead&gt; &amp; &lt;tbody&gt;</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much I understand it know. I was indeed using <thead> and <tbody> which resulted in 2 containers holding <tr> tags.

Comment: Glad I could help :)
I updated the answer to demonstrate it in 3 simple samples for the case anyone stumbles over this question

Answer (score 0):

You may need to reset the browser data on you browser. Especially if you've been playing around with the CSS, this can cause the page to look off.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is true, the first row of the HTML table starts at 0.

For example :

// We have a table containing 3 rows

```
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>Row1 cell1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row2 cell1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row3 cell1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

We are retrieving 0th row

`alert(document.getElementById("myTable").rows[0].innerHTML);`

Output of this will be:

Row1 Cell1

Comment: In JavaScript it's `rows[0]` but the css :nth-child selector always starts at 1 which will apply the nth-child(odd) rule